# Não consigo fazer uma busca com palavras entre colchetes em php

Tags: php, array, algoritmo-de-busca, preg-match

Eu criei uma função para verificar se algumas palavras existem em um array. Eu quero fazer a busca de palavras dentro de colchetes "[ ]".
Exemplo: [como] , [dar], [amar] ...

Para isso, eu estou usando a função preg_match() para verificar se existe alguma das palavras no array. Entretanto, a função está aceitando a verificação das palavras sem os colchetes.

Exemplo: A palavra "darkgreen" é aceita, porque tem "dar" no inicio, mas eu só  quero que aceite "[dar]"

Este é meu código e um exemplo de texto onde faço a verificação:

Meu código:

```
private function existeAlgum($post){
    $saida = array();

    foreach ($this->termos as $termo) {
        $er = "[".$termo."]";
        if(preg_match($er,$post)){
            $saida[] = $termo;
        }
    }

    return $saida;
}
```

Exemplo de array:

```
 <dl>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">como</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[como]</font>  &lt;rel&gt; &lt;ks&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-ADVL</font></b> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-N&lt;</font></b>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">não</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[não]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">amar</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[amar]</font>  &lt;vt&gt; <font color="blue"><b>V</b> FUT 1/3S SUBJ VFIN </font> <font color="darkgreen">@FMV</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">uma</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[um]</font>  &lt;arti&gt; <font color="blue"><b>DET</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;N</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">pessoa</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[pessoa]</font>  &lt;H&gt; <font color="blue"><b>N</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&lt;ACC</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">tão</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[tão]</font>  &lt;dem&gt; &lt;quant&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;A</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">linda</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[lindo]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADJ</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@N&lt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">.</font></b> 

    </dl>
```

Comment: Relacionado pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81863/expressão-regular-para-obter-o-que-há-fora-dos-colchetes/81896

Comment: O que você tem na variável `$this->termos`?

Comment: O  $this->termos contem as palavras: como, dar, amar....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está usando colchetes.
Eles são elementos da sintaxe das espressões regulares.

Além disso, a função ***preg_match*** precisa de um delimitador inicial que nesse caso pode ser o hashtag ***#***. E para aceitar o colchete como parte da string, usa-se o backslash como carácter ***escape***.

Ficando assim:

```
private function existeAlgum($post){
    $saida = array();

    foreach ($this->termos as $termo) {
        $er = "#\\[".$termo."\\]#";
        if(preg_match($er,$post)){
            $saida[] = $termo;
        }
    }

    return $saida;
}
```

Comment: vlw cara funcionou =D